# Is it possible to create a DataFolder as a child of the Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder with the Soap API in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Is it possible to create a DataFolder as a child of the Shared Salesforce Data Extensions folder with the Soap API in Marketing Cloud?

The code below works when the parentFolder is the 'Shared Data Extensions' folder and the ContentType is shared_dataextension, but when the parentFolder is the 'Shared Salesforce Data Extensions' folder and the ContentType is shared_salesforcedataextension, I get an Error 'API Permission Failed' with statuscode 7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="DataFolder">
                <ParentFolder>
                    <ID>{{parentFolderId}}</ID>
                </ParentFolder>
                <CustomerKey>{{$guid}}</CustomerKey>
                <Name>GailSoapyTestDe2</Name>
                <Description>Gail Testing Soap API</Description>
                <ContentType>shared_salesforcedataextension</ContentType>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
                <AllowChildren>true</AllowChildren>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```